# Polymer Library Load Failed

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have created a youtube element in polymer using the `google-youtube` library. I used the `id` of youtube video in the `youtube-element` and the video was showing but it disappeared. 
I checked in `console`, shows error:

`Library Load failed:failed to load Library
Cannot GET /bower_components/polymer/polymer-micro.html.js`

I deleted this library and installed this library again using `bower install`, but I am still getting the same error. I am not able to load the `youtube-element`.
can anyone help here?

Code for `youtube-element.html`

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="youtube-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <h1 class="heading" >MY YouTube Videos</h1>
      <paper-material class="mid" elevation="1">
        <google-youtube
          video-id="HgJ0XCyBwzY"
          height="270px"
          width="480px"
          rel="0"
          start="5"
          autoplay="0">
        </google-youtube>

      </paper-material>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'youtube-element',
        properties: {
          foo: {
            type: String,
            value: 'youtube-element',
            notify: true
          }
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Can you post the code as well?

Comment: I have posted code

Comment: Did you forgot to import `google-youtube`element?

Comment: its there in my elements.html file

Comment: It is working : http://plnkr.co/edit/DNA0xTJhxXMd2O7CJfei?p=preview

Comment: it was the problem of my proxy